# Computation of partial fraction decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Suppose the polynomial $Q(x)$ be $$Q(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2) \cdots (x-\alpha_{n+1})$$, where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots , \alpha_{n+1}$ are distinct real numbers and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial with degree less than $n+1$ then
>   $$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\sum^{n+1}_{k=1}\frac{P(\alpha_k)}{Q'(\alpha_k)(x-\alpha_k)},$$
>   where $Q'(x)$ is the derivative of the polynomial $Q(x)$.

The generalisation of partial fractions decomposition is strongly related to Lagrange polynomial, should I start proving Lagrange polynomial before the statement above? Or I should have another approach to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two polynomials of degree $n$ are equal if they have the same values at $n+1$ distinct points. Multiply RHS and LHS of your equation by $Q(x)$ and compute the obtained LHS and RHS at any $\alpha_j$. If LHS($\alpha_j$)=RHS($\alpha_j$) are the same for all $j=1,...,n+1$ then the equality is true. Do not forget that 
$$
 (\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}(x-\alpha_j))'=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\prod_{i\neq j}(x-\alpha_i).
$$

Comment: So I have to make $r(x)=P(x)-\sum^{n+1}_{k=1}\frac{\alpha_k}{Q'(\alpha_k)(x-\alpha_k)} \cdot Q(x)=0$ holds true for all $\alpha_k$, where $k=1,2, \cdots, n+1$.  Prove that $r(x)$ with degree $n$ has $n+1$ roots, concludes that $r(x)$ must be a zero polynomial, i.e. $r(x)=0$, so the conclusion follows?

Comment: Yes! If a polynomial of degree $n$ has at least $n+1$ roots then it is $0$.   Just a remark: put $P(\alpha_k)$ instead of $\alpha_k$ in the numerator in your comment.

Comment: Oh okay, I have mistyped it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

The decomposition gives

$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{A_k}{(x-\alpha_k)}$$

with

$$A_k=\lim_{x\to\alpha_k}\frac{P(x)(x-\alpha_k)}{Q(x)}$$
and
$$Q'(\alpha_k)=\lim_{x\to\alpha_k}\frac{Q(x)-0}{x-\alpha_k}.$$

You can take it.

Comment: I don't understand how to relate with MVT.